# Lua registered C function calling another one

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

Say I have two C functions registered in my Lua scope:

```
int func1(lua_State* L)
{
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    // Do sth here...
}

int func2(lua_State* L)
{
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    // Do sth here...
}
```

The question is: can I call `func2` within `func1`?

I found out that if several arguments are passed to `func1`, the value that `lua_gettop()` returns in `func2` makes no sense.

For example, if 3 arguments are passed to `func1` in my lua script, `lua_gettop()` returns 3 in `func1`, and no less than 3 in `func2`. This is definitely wrong since `lua_gettop()` should return the number of arguments passed to current function.

So should I do any stack trick before calling `func2` such as setting up new stack frame or just simply should not do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lua_gettop` does not return number of arguments, but rather number of items on your stack. If you mess with the stack in the calling function, it will remain messed up when you directly call another C function.

If you call it via Lua (for example using [`lua_cpcall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_cpcall)), it will start with it own stack state and arguments you give it within Lua.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. This should work for me. I'm using Lua 5.3 and seems the lua_cpcall() function has become deprecated. Now it's an undocumented macro in luaconf.h.

Comment: @babel92 FYI, the [Changes in the API](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.3) section says: *Function `lua_cpcall` is deprecated. You can simply push the function with [`lua_pushcfunction`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pushcfunction) and call it with [`lua_pcall`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pcall).*

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldn't call directly func2 within func1, each function has a local stack.

As @che wrote, `lua_gettop` returns the number of items in your stack, so you can use `lua_gettop` to get the arguments passed to a function because **each function has a local stack**.

That's why for getting the arguments of a function you do like this:

```
lua_tostring(L, 1);
lua_tointeger(L, 2);
lua_to...(L, i);
```

And for returning results you *push* back into the local stack:

```
lua_pushstring(L, "hello");
lua_pushinteger(L, 1);

return 2; // number of arguments returned
```

If you want to call a lua function from C use `lua_pcall`.